# sfDoctrineGuardPlugin - increase session time

Tags: symfony-1.4

I am developing a site using `sfDoctrineGuardPlugin` and I was wondering if there is a way to increase the time that someone is logged in before they are signed out?

I would like to increase the time that the session is stored when a user is logged in, but is idle, but cannot seem to find the right place in the plugin to increase this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default configuration for the `sfUser` class is like this:

```
  user:
    class: myUser
    param:
      timeout:         1800
      logging:         %SF_LOGGING_ENABLED%
      use_flash:       true
      default_culture: %SF_DEFAULT_CULTURE%
```

(found in `lib/vendor/symfony/lib/config/config/factories.yml`).

You can override this in your own application, by adding something like this to your `apps/app/config/factories.yml`:

```
  user:
    class: myUser
    param:
      timeout:         3600
```

I expect the timeout to be in seconds.

Comment: Does this override the `gc_maxlifetime` in the php.ini file?